# Ubuntu will not start due to full partitions

Tags: filesystem, hard-drive

I left my computer downloading all the night and I did download 35 GB of movies (legal ...). I restarted the computed in the morning then I booted in my encrypted Windows partition for my work.

I have left my computer downloading 35GB of files and when I restarted in the morning, I booted Windows. When I tried to access Ubuntu, it failed to boot and in low-graphic mode told me that it won't boot because the partition is full. I tried rescue and it reported 0 MB free.

I also cannot delete files with `sudo rm` as all are impossible due to a read-only file system. I can mount it in Windows but there is a "write protection" there, also.

Should I try a live USB?

Comment: First step: do not panic. Panic leads to trouble and shortens life.

Comment: @rafalcieslak thanks i am not panicking i am pissed off! You dont have a solution?

Comment: @mike Let's not get angry. The main way to solve a problem is to step back and look at the big picture.

Answer (score 3):

When you boot into rescue mode, the filesystem is initially mounted read-only.  To mount it read/write, run:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Then you should be able to delete some files to free up some space.

Answer (score 1):

Try entering recovery mode(or even a terminal in a regular boot). Then, execute each of these commands(fill in the correct partition for `/dev/sd??`, as I am unsure of what it is on your system.

```
sudo mkdir /mount/recover

sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sd?? /mount/recover

cd /mount/recover
```

Now, you can try deleting files using a command-line or if you are able to get a GUI running, delete/interact with them there.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting with a live cd (or usb). You should be able to access your file system and free up some space so that it will boot.

I'm pretty sure Windows can only read EXT3/4 filesystems which is why it said that it is write protected.

Comment: Without special third-party drivers, Windows cannot access `ext2`, `ext3`, and `ext4` filesystems at all.